# can't get routeParams or spyOn to work for angular scope method

Tags: angularjs, jasmine

I'm running into two problems with this test.  First, I'm trying to set up a route parameter of 1 because in my controller, it will only call the loadJob method if the routeParam.id is set.  When I do a console.log of the $routeParams.id in the controller when the test runs, it writes out undefined.  So, I'm not sure why the route parameter isn't making it from the test into the controller.

Secondly, if I comment out the if check on the routeParams and just let it call $scope.loadJob, the spyOn fails.  Any ideas what I'm doing wrong here?

spec -

```
describe('ApplyController', function() {
    var httpBackend, scope, job;

    beforeEach(module('jobBoard'))

    describe('loads the proper job', function(){
        beforeEach(inject(function($rootScope, $controller, $httpBackend, $http, $q, $upload, $log, templates){
            httpBackend = $httpBackend;
            scope = $rootScope.$new();
            job = { id: 1, positionTitle: 'test' };
            httpBackend.when('GET', templates.apiUrl + '/job/1').respond(job);
            $controller('JobController', {
                $scope: scope,
                $routeParams: {id:1},
                $http: $http,
                $q: $q,
                $upload: $upload,
                $log: $log,
                templates: templates
            });
            spyOn(scope, 'loadJob');
        }))

        it('calls loadJob when id route parameter is provided', function(){
            httpBackend.flush();
            scope.$digest();
            expect(scope.loadJob).toHaveBeenCalled();
        })
    })
})
```

controller...

```
angular.module('jobBoard').controller('ApplyController',
    ['$scope','$routeParams', '$http', '$q', '$upload', '$log', 'templates', function($scope, $routeParams, $http, $q, $upload, $log, templates){

        $scope.job = {};
        $scope.pageTitle = '';
        $scope.jobId = 0;

        $scope.loadJob = function(){
            var deferred = $q.defer();

            $http.get(templates.apiUrl + '/job/' + $routeParams.id)
                .success(function(data){
                    $scope.job = data;
                    $scope.pageTitle = $scope.job.position_title;
                    $scope.jobId = $scope.job.id;
                    deferred.resolve(data);
                });
            return deferred.promise;
        }

        if ($routeParams.id) {
            $scope.loadJob();
        }
    }
]);
```

Comment: I just realized the stupid, dumb, idiotic mistake I made.  I wrote the test for the wrong controller lol!

Comment: Well, I spoke too soon.  That took care of the routeParams mistake but for some reason the spyOn is still reporting that the loadJob method isn't being called - even if I comment out the if ($routeParams.id) line.